# Mysql 8 which linux / Unix Distro would have better performance (2021 topic)

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, unix

I want to setup a mysql 8 with MyRocks engine and **BUILD** from source with my custom parameters.

Is there any recommendation on which linux / unix distro would have better performances ?

CentOS stream
FreeBSD
Fedora 34

HARDWARE that I have access to :
Premium Intel with NVMe SSD

I searched on the web for benchmarks but search engines throw anything but that.... :(

If it's the wrong forum to ask this, please tell me where I could ask those questions.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance differences between those distros are so subtle that any of them could be the best choice for a given workload. The only way to get a definitive answer for your workload is for you to run your own benchmarks.

None of them are likely to be a great bottleneck on MySQL, or a great advantage over the others.

I'd recommend that you just pick the one which you are most experienced with, to make administration easier.